# When terraform applies aws_spot_fleet_request, how can I retrieve the private ip addresses?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, aws-sdk, boto3, terraform

If Terraform applies let say 6 EC2 instances as the target capacity as shown in this [example](https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/aws/r/spot_fleet_request.html):

```
# Request a Spot fleet
resource "aws_spot_fleet_request" "cheap_compute" {
  iam_fleet_role      = "arn:aws:iam::12345678:role/spot-fleet"
  spot_price          = "0.03"
  allocation_strategy = "diversified"
  target_capacity     = 6
  valid_until         = "2019-11-04T20:44:20Z"

  launch_specification {
    instance_type             = "m4.10xlarge"
    ami                       = "ami-1234"
    spot_price                = "2.793"
    placement_tenancy         = "dedicated"
    iam_instance_profile_arn  = "${aws_iam_instance_profile.example.arn}"
  }

  launch_specification {
    instance_type             = "m4.4xlarge"
    ami                       = "ami-5678"
    key_name                  = "my-key"
    spot_price                = "1.117"
    iam_instance_profile_arn  = "${aws_iam_instance_profile.example.arn}"
    availability_zone         = "us-west-1a"
    subnet_id                 = "subnet-1234"
    weighted_capacity         = 35

    root_block_device {
      volume_size = "300"
      volume_type = "gp2"
    }

    tags {
      Name = "spot-fleet-example"
    }
  }
}
```

The only available attributes are 'id' and 'spot_request_state'.

How can I output the private IP addresses of the launched instances?

Is this possible or do I need to utilize another tool like Boto3?

Comment: idk about terraform, but you can request further info via a [describe-spot-fleet-instances request with that 'id'](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/spot-fleet-requests.html#manage-spot-fleet)

Comment: That only describes "InstanceId", "InstanceType", "SpotInstanceRequestId","InstanceHealth".

Comment: true but it's easy from there via a describe-instances request using the instance ids

Answer (score 2):

You can utilise `Data Sources` in Terraform. These allow you to essentially perform API calls to retrieve data from AWS. Once you've created your resource you can use the following Terraform -

```
data "aws_instances" "spot-fleet-ips" {
  instance_tags {
    Name = "spot-fleet-example"
  }
}
```

To get the IPs then you can do the following -

```
"${data.aws_instances.spot-fleet-ips.private_ips}"
```

The documentation for the above data source is [here.](https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/aws/d/instances.html#private_ips)

Comment: I think you mean like this added  in the tf file? but I get the error "data.aws_instances.spot-fleet-ips: Your query returned no results".

data "aws_instances" "spot-fleet-ips" {
  instance_tags {
    Name = "spot-fleet-example"
  }
}

output "sfleet requested private ips" {
    value = "${data.aws_instances.spot-fleet-ips.private_ips}"
}

Comment: I think you mean like this added  in the tf file? but I get the error "data.aws_instances.spot-fleet-ips: Your query returned no results".
'code'
data "aws_instances" "spot-fleet-ips" {
  instance_tags {
    Name = "spot-fleet-example"
  }
}

output "sfleet requested private ips" {
    value = "${data.aws_instances.spot-fleet-ips.private_ips}"
}
'code'

Comment: Have the instances been created at the time you are running using the data source? As the instances need to have been created and have a private ip associated to them, otherwise, you need to run the data source when they are created.

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible atm in terraform to obtain the instances of a Spot fleet.

You would require writing codes in AWS SDK / boto3 to find the instances created using Spot fleet. It is the same case for EC2 AutoScaling Groups & EMR Clusters.

Thanks.